# Config file transform of Silverlight projects on a CI server

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, web-config, continuous-integration

I'm stuck with a transformation of the config files in a Silverlight project (i.e. the `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig`-file). I have followed some sources (for example [this source](http://blogs.staykov.net/2011/10/servicereferenceclientconfig-build.html) ) on how to manually edit the .csproj-file to add transformation file, but I cannot get it to work on our CI-server.

The changes to the .csproj-file are:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition="exists('ServiceReferences.$(Configuration).ClientConfig')">
<TransformXml Source="ServiceReferences.ClientConfig" Destination="$(TargetDir)\ServiceReferences.ClientConfig" Transform="ServiceReferences.$(Configuration).ClientConfig" />
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Remove="ServiceReferences.ClientConfig" />
  <ContentWithTargetPath Include="$(TargetDir)\ServiceReferences.ClientConfig">
    <TargetPath>ServiceReferences.ClientConfig</TargetPath>
  </ContentWithTargetPath>
</ItemGroup>
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild" />
```

The transformation of my configuration files works fine if I *build my Silverlight project in VS2010 on my local client*. I can open the generated XAP-file and look at `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` and see that it is transformed. Hence, I rule out the transformation file(s) as the problem.

But when I build my Silverlight project on our CI-server, the `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` remains untransformed in the generated XAP-file on the CI-server.

Regarding the Build Definition, I is okay as far as I can see. `DeployConfiguration` in the `Processes` section is set to a valid configuration. (If I change the name of the configuration in this entry, to something not valid - the CI-server will complain. Thus it works so far...) `Transform Configuration Files`in the same section is set to true.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem myself - the problem is that I'm stupid.

Basically, the name of the Active Solution Configuration in the solution was correct, i.e. `ProductionTest`. The transform file had the name `ServiceReferences.ProductionTest.ClientConfig`. So far so good. However, the name of the *Project Configuration* for the Silverlight project was `Release`. So TransformXML tried to use the (non existing) transform file `ServiceReferences.Release.ClientConfig`. Since the existence of the correct configuration file was a condition for `BeforeBuild`, TransformXML would never execute - nor would I have any error messages.

Changing the Project Configuration to `ProductionTest` solved everything.